# Strange vim/xterm interaction: auto-insertion of `"` register when opening file

Tags: register, startup

This one is driving me mad. I'm using XTerm(330) and the latest vim 8.0.1365 (on FreeBSD).

Sometimes, not always, about 1 in 5, when I open a file with vim, a funny line is inserted above line 1. After a lot of head scratching, I realized it is the last line I deleted in a previous session. In other words, it looks like `""P` (paste the `"` register) is run.

After some more investigation, I found this only happens when I have `*sunKeyboard: true` set in the XTerm resources, and when I use a rendered font, such as `-fa "DejaVu Sans Mono:size=24"`. (I told you it was strange, didn't I?). I have no `.vimrc` and no `.vim` directory, to avoid any plugin playing tricks on me.

I can reproduce the effect somewhat with the following commands:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -f .viminfo; echo inserted >bar; echo x >baz
vim -c d -c wq bar
echo '*sunKeyboard: true' > XTerm
export XAPPLRESDIR=$PWD
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
   xterm -fa "DejaVu Sans Mono:size=24" -e vim baz
done
```

This will create the necessary files, place `inserted` in the `"` register and invoke vim a few times. If you see a one line file with `x` in the first line, all is fine; enter `q` for the next invocation. If however you see

```
inserte2
x
```

you have reproduced the problem. Note also that the last character of line 1 has been replaced by `2`. This seems to come from the `.` register. Here are the registers:

```
:reg
--- Registers ---
""   inserted^J
"1   inserted^J
".   2
"%   baz
```

- Trying the script several times, can you reproduce the problem? Be sure to move `.vimrc` and `.vim` temporarily out of the way.
- If so, can you tell me what is going on here?
- Any suggestions how to get to the bottom of this?

**UPDATE**

Looks like I'm not the only one: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2238

Comment: Does either `set t_RS=` or `set t_SH=` in your vimrc work?

Comment: @Mass Yes, either of them works, i.e. no more magic line insertion. With these entries the `:reg` command no longer shows the `".` contents.

Comment: Have you checked if https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/2126 fixes your issue? What exactly is the output of `:echo v:termresponse`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt The output is `^[[>19;331;0c`. The github page is a twisty little maze I have no idea how to glean information from. Near the bottom it says "closed", but I can't seem to find a patch number, such as "fixed in 8.0.####". Thanks for taking the time to comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When vim starts up, it interrogates your terminal emulator, which responds with terminal codes.  vim usually captures this in `v:termresponse`.  Sometimes, however, the codes get through and they frequently look like vim commands and cause unintended behavior.

Two of the options which controls what *vim* sends seem to cause many people issues:

```
t_RS    request terminal cursor style           *t_RS* *'t_RS'*
t_SH    set cursor shape                        *t_SH* *'t_SH'*
```

These were added recently to allow vim to set the cursor shape and determine the default terminal cursor.  Setting either of these to empty (`set t_SH=` or `set t_RS=`) causes vim to skip the check.  It is the response from your terminal which is causing the problem.

This is most likely a vim bug, because it should work by default in xterm.  Besides setting these options to empty, I suggest,

- updating to the most recent vim version
- report the bug (see `:h bugs`), carefully noting your platform and terminal emulator, the precise behavior seen, and the value of `v:termresponse`.