# How do I make vim's terminal use my emulator's cursor shape?

Tags: terminal, cursor

I am using `ibeam` a.k.a `vertical bar` cursor right now. When I switch to `terminal` mode in `vim`, it changes the cursor shape to `block` - but doesn't restore it after I quit the `terminal`.

I tried changing it in my shell as per the below comment; it works for `:terminal` but not for `:terminal tig`.

`:help terminal` has a section called `terminal-cursor-style`, but I am not able sure what to do with that information.

Is it possible to inherit the terminal emulator's cursor shape inside `vim` -- if not, can I at-least configure it to us my cursor style?

Comment: well, the cursor style is usually defined using some xterm escape sequences. If you know the correct escape sequences to make an `ibeam` cursor (whatever that is), simply run it in Vims terminal and it should adjust the cursor accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianBrabandt, I could probably use `echo -e -n "\x1b[\x35 q"`. I would like know if this is configurable + if I can re-use this info from my terminal and not repeat it.

Comment: don't think so and I think such a configuration option belongs into your `.bashrc` or similar shell configuration file.

Comment: `[[ $TERM == xterm* ]] && echo -e -n "\x1b[\x35 q"` works when you simply do `:terminal`. But when you do something like `:terminal tig` and come back, it changes back to block cursor.

Comment: this `[[ $TERM == xterm* ]] && echo -e -n "\x1b[\x35 q"`, doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14529/10652

`set t_SH=6` might be what you are looking for...

```
t_SH must take one argument:
        0, 1 or none    blinking block cursor
        2               block cursor
        3               blinking underline cursor
        4               underline cursor
        5               blinking vertical bar cursor
        6               vertical bar cursor
```